# R append a new row to each row

Tags: r

I would like to insert a row into each beighboring rows, for example, the orginal data frame like this:

```
ID x y z value
1  1 1 1 2
2  4 7 9 3
3  9 2 5 8
4  8 6 1 4
5  7 3 5 9
```

And after inserting rows, the data frame should be like this:

```
ID x y z value
1  1 1 1 2
3  5 NA NA NA
2  4 7 9 3
8  1 NA NA NA
3  9 2 5 8
6  3 NA NA NA
4  8 6 1 4
9  7 NA NA NA
5  7 3 5 9
10 8 NA NA NA
```

I get two options, the first is appending new row to each row directly, and the second is add two columns to the dataframe, and then split a row into two rows.
So how to deal with this situation? Thank you in advance!

Comment: a. why, and  b. where are the `x` values coming from?

Comment: Hi, please set ID and x value of the new rows to any intergers.

Comment: You haven't answered a., so I'm pretty sure I'm enabling a truly abominable course of action, but here you go: `do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x){data.frame(rbind(x, c(rpois(2, 5), rep(NA, 3))))}))`

Comment: or taking a different tack, `merge(df, data.frame(ID = 1:5, x = rpois(5, 5), y = NA), all = TRUE)`

Comment: Hi, actually my project reads each two rows as parameters,  so I want to append a new row to each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to understand where you are getting the data that you wish to insert into the data frame. So, I made a dummy set `data2`. Please refer code below, should work for what you need.

```
data <- read.table(text= "ID x y z value
                   1  1 1 1 2
                   2  4 7 9 3
                   3  9 2 5 8
                   4  8 6 1 4
                   5  7 3 5 9", header=T)

data2 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(2*nrow(data)),nrow(data)))
names(data2) <- names(data)[1:ncol(data2)]

combined <- plyr::rbind.fill(data,data2)
n <- nrow(data)
combined[kronecker(1:n, c(0, n), "+"),]
```